# Responsive images using background-image over img attribute

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I am making a responsive website where I have used the img attribute in the HTML markup so that images scale nicely, to the point where they are moved about with media queries.

(Similar to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QfDv5/  except I have used seperate images.)

However, for ease of updating, I want to add the image paths to the css file instead of the HTML markup. I thought the img-background attribute would be good to do this. That said, I want to stay away from 'background-size' attribute since older browsers don't play nice with it.

I thought of making an element within each of the scaling class divs. The div scales horizontally **IF** I declare a fixed height, but I cannot seem to get it to scale vertically automatically. I added:

```
#test-2{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url("http://www.desibucket.com/db2/01/26039/26039.jpg");
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rE4G8/)

1. What am I missing in getting the new element to scale without a fixed height?
2. How can I get the actual background image to scale with the new element?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is using media queries and set the exact height you want.

```
media screen and (min-width: 1234px) and (min-height:700px) {
image {height: xxxpx;}
}
```

Comment: Yea I feared I would have to settle for an adaptive solution over a truly scalable responsive solution. Thanks anyway.